# Android emulator has no options anymore

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Last week when I wanted to debug my app in android emulator, the window had a toolbar on the right side with buttons, to set GPS position, zoom the screen, etc. The emulator window also was resisable.

[image: Like this]

And I don't know what I did, but now there's no toolbar anymore, window is not resizable... I didn't change the avd configuration. Does anyone know what I can do to get the emulator as it was ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by installing SDK tools 25.0.1 rc2. The error I made was to install SDK tools 24.4.1 which replaced the version 25.0.1 previsouly installed.